# Developing Jquery Splitter

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

How to write jquery for Splitter? or is there any good plugin for jquery splitter? I need two column splitter made in jquery.

Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking for **split panes**, not column splitters. Try [this one](http://yaxu.org/synth/jquery/demos/real-world/splitpane/) out based on jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't under stand your question clearly.I think you want some thing like this.

```
 var string= "a_b_c_d";
 var arrVal = new Array();
 arrVal = string.split("_");<br>
```

and u can catch its value
 
 `var a =arrVal[0];`
and so on.

Comment: No.. I am talking about Jquery Splitter Component. Anyways thanks for your reply :)